MUI 5 + Emotion styled not reading secondary color only
I have an app with Mui 5.8.1
I'm also using emotion styled library.
I followed guide to typescript and I've set up some custom colors with custom shades:
import { PaletteColor, Theme as MuiTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import '@emotion/react';
interface CustomPaletteColor extends PaletteColor {
    v50: string;
    v100: string;
    v200: string;
    v300: string;
    v400: string;
    v500: string;
    v600: string;
    v700: string;
    v800: string;
    v900: string;
    v950: string;
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Palette {
        paper: CustomPaletteColor;
        primary: CustomPaletteColor;
        secondary: CustomPaletteColor;
        secondaryCustom: CustomPaletteColor;
        tertiary: CustomPaletteColor;
        gold: CustomPaletteColor;
        bg: {
            light: string;
            main: string;
            dark: string;
        };
    }

    interface PaletteOptions {
        paper?: Partial<CustomPaletteColor>;
        primary?: Partial<CustomPaletteColor>;
        secondary?: Partial<CustomPaletteColor>;
        secondaryCustom?: Partial<CustomPaletteColor>;
        tertiary?: Partial<CustomPaletteColor>;
        gold?: Partial<CustomPaletteColor>;
        bg?: {
            light?: string;
            main?: string;
            dark?: string;
        };
    }
}

// Simplify color overrides for various components
type CustomColors =
    | 'paper'
    | 'primary'
    | 'secondary'
    | 'secondaryCustom'
    | 'tertiary'
    | 'gold'
    | 'bg';

declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
    interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides extends Record<CustomColors, true> {}
}

declare module '@mui/material/IconButton' {
    interface IconButtonPropsColorOverrides
        extends Record<CustomColors, true> {}
}

declare module '@mui/material/Fab' {
    interface FabPropsColorOverrides extends Record<CustomColors, true> {}
}

declare module '@emotion/react' {
    export interface Theme extends MuiTheme {}
}

However, Typescript cannot read the secondary color stages; The following code returns an error:
const MyButton = styled(Button)`
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.secondary.v300};
`;
// Property 'v300' does not exist on type 'PaletteColor'.

However, it works with secondary custom color, that I added for testing:
const MyButton = styled(Button)`
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.secondaryCustom.v300};
`;

It seems like it has only problem with the secondary name. I already checked some declarations file that may overwrite it and I found nothing. Anyone?
